# How do API work with CORS policies to serve multiple apps

Tags: ajax, web-services, cors

I am creating an API that would serve data to my frontend app. The API is on api.myapp.com and the app on [www.myapp.com](http://www.myapp.com) (same domain, just another subdomain). They communicate with AJAX requests and CORS is all set up, working fine.

But I have another app on another domain ([www.myotherapp.com](http://www.myotherapp.com)) which partialy uses the same data as myapp, so I was thinking of reusing the API so myotherapp could requests data from it too.

I think it is one use case of API, to be reusable, right?

But then, there is something that I may have missed, because as my API has CORS enabled with "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: www.myapp.com", it won't allow other apps to use its endpoints, right? Their AJAX requests would fail with CORS policies.

So how are public API built and configured? How should I set my API so it can serve several apps (ideally, only the ones I allow)?

Thanks for the explanations :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an **Origin** header in the request and your API should check if this header is one of the allowed. If it is, then return it as an **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header.

If the API is public, it can returns * as **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header.

Comment: Ah right! I read many "hacks" to allow multiple origins but only from a specific whitelist, as it seems not possible to list multiple domains into Access-Control-Allow-Origin. But indeed, if the API is public, then "*" is the solution!